# Forcing socket.connect to wait a specific time before it decides a connection is unavailable

Tags: java, sockets

I'm issuing a socket connection, using the following snippet

```
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        InetSocketAddress endPoint = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 1234);
        try
        {
            socket.connect(endPoint, 30000);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Logging
        }
```

The endpoint it is trying to connect to is offline, what I want it to do is to attempt to connect, and using the `30000`ms timeout, wait for that period of time before it concludes a result

Currently, that `30000` parameter doesn't seem to be applied, as from the timestamp on my logging it appears that it is determining within 1 second that a connection failed.

How can I force the connect to wait for a set amount of time before giving up?

```
13:13:57,685 6235 DEBUG [Thread-7]     - Unable to connect to [localhost:1234]
13:13:58,685 7235 DEBUG [Thread-7]     - Unable to connect to [localhost:1234]
13:13:59,695 8245 DEBUG [Thread-7]     - Unable to connect to [localhost:1234]
13:14:00,695 9245 DEBUG [Thread-7]     - Unable to connect to [localhost:1234]
```

EDIT :  The [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29) does state `Connects this socket to the server with a specified timeout value. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. The connection will then block until established or an error occurs.` however it appears I'm not experiencing such behaviour, or am not catering to it, most likely the latter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're getting here is correct. connect won't sit on a socket waiting until it sees a server, it will attempt to connect and wait for a response.  if there is nothing to connect to, it returns.  if there is something to connect to, it will wait *timeout* seconds for a response and fail if none is received.

Answer (score 3):

You need to distinguish among several possible exception conditions.

1. `ConnectException` with the text 'connection refused', which means the host was up and reachable and nothing was listening at the port. This happens very quickly and cannot be subjected to a timeout.
2. `NoRouteToHostException`: this indicates a connectivity issue. Again it happens immediately and cannot be subjected to a timeout.
3. `UnknownHostException`: the host names cannot be resolved via DNS. This happens immediately, or rather after a generally short DNS delay, and cannot be subjected to a timeout.
4. `ConnectException` with any other text: this can indicate a failure to respond by the target system. Usually happens when firewalls are present. Can be subjected to a timeout.

You are doing the correct thing by calling `Socket.connect()` with a timeout parameter. If you don't do this, or if you specify a zero timeout, the default system timeout is used, which is of the order of 60-75 seconds depending on the platform. This is contrary to the Javadoc's statement about an 'infinite timeout', which is not correct. Also you cannot *increase* the timeout beyond this limit via `Socket.connect()` witha a timeout parameter. Alternatively you can use `java.nio` socket channels in non-blocking mode with a `select()` to administer the timeout for you, but you still can't increase the timeout beyond the platform default via this or any other method.

Answer (score 0):

When the timeout occurs, a SocketTimeoutException exception is thrown which you do not catch and log. The IOException is fired when "an error occurs during the connection". The timeout is never applied because there's an error beforehand.

Edit: Just to clarify: TCP/IP as a suite has many specifics that could prevent a packet from reaching it's desired outcome (a SYN/ACK packet). If a computer responds to your SYN packet by an informing your application that the port is closed (i.e. there's no application running/listening there), it would fire an exception telling you that it is *impossible* to connect to that port. If you wish to send and re-send SYN packets either way with the knowledge that an application will come online listening on that port, this is done on a different network layer (and, as far as I know, is not accessible with Java out-of-the-box).

Comment: As the exception is thrown by the connect() method, it can also occur while connecting.

Comment: `SocketTimeoutException` extends `IOException`, so he does catch and log it. There is no 'error beforehand'. The timeout, connection refusal etc., *is* the error. 'This' [send and resend] is not done on any network layer at all, but it can be done by an application, including Java applications.

Answer (score -1):

Try scocket.setSoTimeout(timeout) before connecting.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried ` socket.setSoTimeout(30000);` before `socket.connect()` but same behaviour.

Comment: That sets a *read* timeout, not a connection timeout. Your answer is incorrect.